# pagination from API react how to detect last item

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, pagination

i've got an API where url is created with current page and last page like https://url.com/currentPage=20?PageSize=20 - but I want to show all doesn't matter how they will change in my API object I've got items and there is respone from that API and totalItems where is original length - i want to make it in this way, where is an update i want to expand that pagesize not only 20. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In server-side pagination, we definitely get this 3 kind of params either in header or
in response

```
"page_number": 5,
"page_size": 20,
"total_record_count": 521,
```

you can simply send total_records_cuount as pageSize in your URL to get all the records.

Comment: any ideas how to work with react-grid pagination with that?

Comment: can you plz create a code sandbox so i can update it according to requirement

Comment: if you want to get all the records in the first API call then you need to ask your API provider to give you the API accordingly

Comment: see this sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/iikzu?file=/demo.js)

Comment: and update this tag like
` <PagingPanel
          pageSizes={[10, 20, 30, 50]}
        />`

Comment: thank you for helping :) I figured out cus react-grid has some problem with that..